# PHP file_get_contents to get the result of a combined GET POST method

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

**I want to catch** with "file_get_contents" or some other method the result of a combined GET/POST request **in a file**.

The URL already contains some GET Variables like for example

```
https://www.example.com/?var1=val1&$var2=val2
```

and I want to catch the result of a POST like

```
<form action="https://www.example.com/?var1=val1&$var2=val2">
<input type="hidden" name="var3" value="val3">
<input type="submit" name="var4" value="val4">
</form>
```

can someone please give some hints ? or point to some documentation?

UPDATE: (my english is also not so good) this is why I will go on with asking in a more complex way.

Bart shows [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php#108309) a example how **file_get_contents** can make a post. What I am missing is how to also send the POST vars (text/hidden/radio/submit) in this example.
Hope now its more clear.

Comment: `$_GET` provides GET variables, `$_POST` provides POSTed variables. You can also use `$_SERVER` for server variables including URL, path, request method, etc. You can access both in the same script.

Comment: Are you asking how to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php) 
 (that's the normal way to emit a http request)?

Comment: I don't think "copy the docs into an answer for me" is appropriate @HenryStack. There are also [at least eight thousand similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+curl+post) already

Comment: @JonJ, thanks for the hint. I want to catch the HTML code of that request in a file. With file_get_contents or curl or another method.

Comment: Are the files on your server? You could use `include` and set the `POST` and `GET` manually prior to the include

Comment: @user3783243 they are not. I want to read html code in a file

Comment: You will need to use CURL in that case. Maybe this is a good thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to catch both get and post.

```
// from the querystring, GET
$var1 = $_GET['var1']
$var2 = $_GET['var2']

// from the posted variables POST
$var3 = $_POST['var3']
$var4 = $_POST['var4']
```

Because I’m Korean middle school student, I can misunderstand your question. If my answer is wrong, please reply to me

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a sniplet from Mr. Martini: you must use **http_build_query** to build the variables array and feed it in the opts array.

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```